# MySQL using MAX() with WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am having some issues creating a mySQL query with PHP. We have one table, called data_instant, with a series of cumulative observations being entered, called Count_Qty, and we want to extract the previous one to deduct from the new observation to calculate the increase.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *, 
MAX(Record_Time) 
FROM data_instant 
WHERE Node_ID='$nodeID' AND Type='$type';

$row = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
```

Basically I'd expect the max Record_Time row to be returned, but instead it's just the first instance that's received. The previous observation has the highest Record_Time (a Unix datestamp), so it's unclear to me why this would not work...

Comment: Wild guesses, is the observation you expect not selected by the WHERE restrictions? or is your `Record_Time` not actually an integer type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to get the row with the latest `Record_Time` value, just sort the rows in the descending order of `Record_Time` and get the top row:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_instant
WHERE Node_ID='$nodeID'
  AND Type='$type'
ORDER BY Record_Time DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Good answer, this is obvious after you explained it, but I've been looking for this for about an hour.

Comment: This works, but is there a way to do it without sorting the entire result? Will the query optimizer find an efficient way to find the max?

Comment: @adamF: Well, I'm not sure you can determine if a value is greater than any other value in a set without going through the entire set. As for your second question, sorry, don't have much knowledge about the query optimiser (at least not about the MySQL one). But then I wouldn't worry about whether the query optimiser *can* come up with a good execution plan for my query. Express your request as simply as possible and let the optimiser find the best way to run it – that's what it is there for, after all. *If/when* there are issues with performance, *then* start thinking of ways to improve it.

Comment: Well sorting takes O(nlgn), but finding the max element only takes O(n). My guess is the optimizer recognizes the pattern order by desc limit k and finds the k max elements (provided k<<n) in sorted order. But you're right, I'll look into it if and when when it causes problems... just curious :)

Answer (score 1):

The `where` clause selects all rows matching Node_ID='$nodeID' AND Type='$type'.

For each of those rows it will return all fields and the maximum record time.

If you want the row with the maximum record time you need to add that to your `where` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data_instant 
WHERE Node_ID='$nodeID' AND Type='$type' 
and Record_Time = (select MAX(Record_Time) 
        FROM data_instant 
        WHERE Node_ID='$nodeID' 
        AND Type='$type')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than the MAX being returned you should add the `GROUP BY` to your statement to ensure the correct aggregation:

```
SELECT columnA,
    columnB, 
    MAX(Record_Time) 
FROM data_instant 
WHERE Node_ID='$nodeID' AND Type='$type'
GROUP BY columnA, columnB;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'd expect the max Record_Time row to be returned

Then you should just ask for that column:

```
SELECT MAX(Record_Time) FROM data_instant 
WHERE Node_ID='$nodeID' AND Type='$type'
```

This will return the max record_time for the specified node_id and type.